# Configuration system faild to initialize , c# , vs2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, app-config

I have a WPF application and I need to work with app.config file.
When I tried to build one by adding a new app.config to my project and then add an appSettings  to the file , I couldn't read the defined keys from the app.config , I was always getting a null.
Then generated app.config file by going to my project's properties, settings and there I defined the values that I needed to use in my application and everything worked just fine . 
But when I needed to save some values to the config file , I had problems : it didn't work when I tried to add a new setting and define it as a user scope (for editing it in the application) - it just wouldn't save the value in the config file.
And when I added manually the appSettings section in the config file and run the application for the first time it did saved the values but the next time I wanted to use those values , the application throw an exception - "Configuration system failed to initialize" .
I removed some .vshost files from the c:Users\myuser\AppData\Local\companyName\filename.vshost path that was written in the inner exception and then my application worked again.

I worked as suggested in this post - [read write app.config file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0)

But my problem is how to save the values in the app.config and how to read them later , all the solutions in the internet don't work - the application just doesn't save the values... I dont know what to do...

Comment: Important note: The custom values of user scope settings are NOT saved to the app.config. They are saved somewhere in the users %AppData% folder. That might be the reason why you think that the values are not saved.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth A.....ok , thanks , so how can I save value in my app.config? I am having a lot of trouble with that :(

Comment: It's not supported by the configuration system for a very good reason: Programs are normally installed in %ProgramFiles% which is read-only for normal users. Why do you need to save values to the app.config?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have an application which needs to know the last project name it was working on , and when the application starts it needs this information in order to start the last project...

Comment: And why is the saved value using the normal user scope mechanism not enough for you?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The values are not saved there.....

Comment: @DanielHilgarth ok , now I have tried again and the values were saved to the app.config :) sorry for the trouble... and thanks for helping me.....:)

Answer (score 1):

I found that once used User Scope variables, trying removing all of them results in such crash.
After trying to change all User Scope settings to Application Scope I ended up putting a dummy User Scope settings which resolve this exception.